# Is there a way to use the scanner().nextLine method to label a specific name with a number the future lines if they have the same name

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to find a way where if I scan the following text file,

```
Tom Cat,mouse.pizza,yes,10 - pizza,vegetable
Don Dog,zoe.justice,yes,10 - pizza,vegetable
Michael Pog,james.george,yes,10 - pizza,vegetable
Judy Elsa,lawrence.holden,no,10 - pizza,vegetable
Ooga Balooga,james.george,yes,10 - pizza,vegetable
James Harnold Pop,animal.lover,yes,10 - pizza,vegetable
Pizza Lover One,james.george,yes,10 - pizza,vegetable
Animal Instincts Two,james.george,yes,10 - pizza,vegetable
Jacob House,james.george,no,10 - Analyst,pizza,vegetable
Larry Lobster,harold.father,yes,10 - pizza,vegetable
Sponge Eater,donald.boo,no,10 - pizza,vegetable
Tristan Baloonga,james.george,yes,10 - pizza,vegetable
```

I would be able to label mouse.pizza as 1, zoe.justice as 2, james.george as 3, animal.lover as 4, james.george as 3 again, james.george as 3, james.george as 3, harold.father as 5, donald.boo as 6, james.george as 3.

I currently have this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
int id2 = 0;
int rid = id2;

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
String line = scanner.nextLine();
String name = line;
String[] parts = name.split(",");
String fullname = parts[1];
String name2;
name2 = scanner.next();
String[] parts2 = name2.split(",");
String fullname2 = parts2[1];
          
if(fullname == fullname2){

recruiterid = id2;
}
        
else {
rid = id2++;
}
```

And it seems like I'm unable to get the code compile correctly. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean under *to label*?

Comment: You can't use a Scanner to label anything. All it does is read from an input stream, which can be a file. Your code will have to do whatever labeling you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Map<String, Integer> labels = new HashMap<>();
int[] n = {0};
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        int label = labels.computeIfAbsent(line.split(",")[1], k -> ++n[0]);
        System.out.println(label + " : " + line);
    }
}
```

output

```
1 : Tom Cat,mouse.pizza,yes,10 - pizza,vegetable
2 : Don Dog,zoe.justice,yes,10 - pizza,vegetable
3 : Michael Pog,james.george,yes,10 - pizza,vegetable
4 : Judy Elsa,lawrence.holden,no,10 - pizza,vegetable
3 : Ooga Balooga,james.george,yes,10 - pizza,vegetable
5 : James Harnold Pop,animal.lover,yes,10 - pizza,vegetable
3 : Pizza Lover One,james.george,yes,10 - pizza,vegetable
3 : Animal Instincts Two,james.george,yes,10 - pizza,vegetable
3 : Jacob House,james.george,no,10 - Analyst,pizza,vegetable
6 : Larry Lobster,harold.father,yes,10 - pizza,vegetable
7 : Sponge Eater,donald.boo,no,10 - pizza,vegetable
3 : Tristan Baloonga,james.george,yes,10 - pizza,vegetable
```